# Overlapping dependent time series, ML problem approach

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, random-forest, correlation

Below is a simplified description of the problem:

Three weeks before delivery of a product a estimation of what the qty will be delivered on a certain demand date is given by the buyer.

This quantity might change as times comes closer to delivery (Illustrated in the image below). This seems quite straight forward but there is a high correlation between the Demand weeks. e.g if a qty is lowered for one week its likely that a surrounding week will increase.

Is there an approach that will get the model to acknowledge the surrounding demand weeks?

[image]

I'm currently using random forest regression with the attributes shown in the image and the results are OK  but I thought asking for inspiration here might be a good idea.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML methodology.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [general questions about machine learning should be posted to their specific communities](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 2):

From your description I understood, that you are currently using only the forecasts of the buyer as an input. And what you would like to do is to also consider the actual Qty of the last week(s) as an input for the next estimation. To achieve this you could create another column in your table that is the actual Qty shifted by one week. That way you get a new column "Actual Qty previous week". Then you can train your model to try to predict using both the buyer forecast and the actual Qty from last week. Of cause you can do the thing once more and shift by two weeks to also make the week before that available.

In addition you can also come up with more elaborate calculated features. One idea would be the average deviation of the buyer-forecast from the final demand (where you take the average for e.g. the last 10 weeks). That way you would be able to detect that some buyers tend to overestimate and some tend to underestimate.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned that variations of qty are influencing the subsequent weeks, I propose to just do tha: create a new feature that is going to show the variation.

This implies to run the predictive algorithm iteratively one week after the other, adding each time a new feature to the dataset: the variation of predicted total quantity for previous weeks.

The method would go like this:

- run prediction model for week1
- add a feature to the dataset: variation of predicted qty for week 1
- run prediction model for week2
- add a feature to the dataset: variation of predicted qty for week 1 + week 2
- run prediction model for week3
- etc ...

This is of course only the idea. It is possible to add different kind of features (variation of last week only, moving average of last weeks, whatever would make sense,...)